# Invalid dustrubution -andas warning

Tags: python, pip

I am getting a warning while updating the pip version or running any pip command :

```
C:\Users\Jay>pip install --upgrade pip
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -andas (c:\python 3.9.6\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -andas (c:\python 3.9.6\lib\site-packages)
```

So what should i do to resolve this issue

Comment: `-andas` or `pandas` ?

Comment: its andas as you cans see the error its andas in site packages